# Footprint is Driving Me Crazy!

Tags: switches, footprint

I'm trying to make a footprint for this switch:
https://www.ckswitches.com/media/1910/rm.pdf

They don't list the XY locations of the pins, just that they are 45 degrees apart but with some trouble I was able to calculate the positions. There are 3 mounting pins that are 120 degrees apart but I cannot find anything on the datasheet that tells me how far apart they are from the center. Am I missing something?
[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the three plastic posts are just intended as spacers to keep the switch body a bit above the PC board - the suggested PC layout doesn't show any holes for them.

Comment: You're not meant to put holes for those; they're standoffs, not plastic rivets. If you were meant to have holes for them, they would be marked in the recommended footprint (where it says "PCB layout").

Comment: Incidentally, you shouldn't need any calculation to place the circular ring of through holes; every layout software I've ever used has a circular array function.

Comment: Thanks I tried looking up "rotating footprint degrees" but since you posted arrays I've been able to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You aren't meant to provide any drill holes for these features. They are meant to rest on the top surface on the top surface of the board, allowing the actuator to be accurately located relative to the PCB surface:

[image]

This means that the exact location of these posts is not critical. You should probably provide a keep out for tracks in the general area to avoid them damaging small copper features on the board, but you don't need to locate them as accurately as you would have to in order to provide mounting holes for them.

If you really need to know the post locations, you can download a CAD model (2D or 3D) of your specific PN from the C&K website, and extract the location from that:
[image]